# Почему не "выключается" каскадное удаление?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

При помощи [fluent api](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx) выключаю каскадное удаление:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityVersion>()
    .HasOptional<Blank>(s => s.Blank)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

но в коде миграции каскадное удаление включено:

```
CreateTable("dbo.EntityVersions",c => new { ... })
    .ForeignKey("dbo.HandbookItems", t => t.BlankId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.BlankId);
```

Почему так происходит?

Если в коде полученной миграции *переопределить* значение `cascadeDelete` на `false`, то все заработает как надо, вопрос собственно состоит в том почему так происходит?